# Should I use 'is caused by' or 'was caused by' here?

Tags: past-tense

> Functional extinction of northern white rhinoceros is caused by two major factors which are excessive poaching and loss of habitat

Can anyone help me to determine if the 'is caused by' is used correctly, or should it be 'was caused by'?

Comment: Your title says is caused not was caused.

Answer (score 1):

- If the White Rhino is already extinct, you would you would use the past tense and say *was caused by*.
- If the White Rhino is going extinct but not yet extinct, you would use present continuous tense and say *is being caused by*.  This indicates the conditions causing the extinction have occurred in the past and still occur in the present but that the actual extinction has not yet occurred.

Comment: thank you very much for your help! so I need to stick to using present continuous for this one as it is going to extinct

Comment: @Kayla Maybe.  I think it depends on what *functional extinction* means.  Perhaps functional extinction has already occurred?